# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE Show number of imported rows

Tags: mysql, file-io, load, local

I am working on a page where the client can select the CSV file to import data into their database. After successful import, I would like to show e.g. "50 Records Inserted". I am unsure if `mysql_affected_rows()` will do this while using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE... since it is not showing any message.

```html
if ((isset($_POST["MM_import"])) && ($_POST["MM_import"] == "confirm_import")) {

              $importSQL = sprintf("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$data_file' INTO TABLE digi_form FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' IGNORE 1 ROWS");

              mysql_select_db($database_MBM, $MBM);
              $Result2 = mysql_query($importSQL, $MBM) or die(mysql_error());             
              printf ("Records deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());

              $insertGoTo = "process-importdata.php";
              if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
                $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
                $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
              }
              header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function [mysql_info()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-info.php)

```
// ...
$Result2 = mysql_query($importSQL, $MBM) or die(mysql_error());           
printf ("Information: %s\n", mysql_info());
```

to get this information, that LOAD DATE INFILE returns:

> When the LOAD DATA INFILE statement finishes, it returns an
> information string in the following format:
>
> Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

Source: [LOAD DATA INFILE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am not that big of an expert when it comes to PHP and MySQL, but I know a bit more than the basic, therefore I am not sure if this question might sound a bit dumb - I have added the mysql_info() function to my code, but i still do not see any message showing the number of records added. The form action is set to submit to itself, or do I have to echo the function somewhere else also?

Comment: After a lot of trial-and-error, I have done the following that works perfectly. For some reason I had to save the mysql_info() function in a variable I called $mysql_info first, then I had to return the mysql_info() function by adding return $mysql_info. Now everything works great!